# OpenGL luminance to color mapping?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I was wondering if there was a way I could process OpenGL texture buffers so that a buffer of grayscale values is converted to rgb values on the fly through some formula of my choosing.

I already have a function like, which works well but outputs a color 3 vector.

```
rgb convertToColor(float value);
```

I am very new to OpenGL and was wondering what kind of shader I should use and where it should go. My program currently cycles frames as such:

```
program1.bind();
program1.setUniformValue("texture", 0);
program1.enableAttributeArray(vertexAttr1);
program1.enableAttributeArray(vertexTexr1);
program1.setAttributeArray(vertexAttr1, vertices.constData());
program1.setAttributeArray(vertexTexr1, texCoords.constData());
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,widthGL,heightGL, GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &displayBuff[displayStart]);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
//...
```

Shader

```
QGLShader *fshader1 = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Fragment, this);
    const char *fsrc1 =
        "uniform sampler2D texture;\n"
        "varying mediump vec4 texc;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texc.st);\n"
        "}\n";
```

I am trying to recreate effects in matlab like imagesc as seen for example in the image below:
[image: imagesc]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
    "uniform sampler2D texture;\n"
    "uniform sampler1D mappingTexture;\n"
    "varying mediump vec4 texc;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    gl_FragColor = texture1D(mappingTexture, texture2D(texture, texc.st).s);\n"
    "}\n";
```

where mapping texture is 1D textuer that maps grayscale to color.

Of course, you could also write function that calculates rgb color based on grayscale, but (depending on your hardware) it might be faster just to do texture lookup.

> it is not clear how to bind two buffers to an OpenGL program at once

[Binding textures to samplers.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Sampler#Binding_textures_to_samplers)

Comment: This is a good answer, but I am finding the learning curve incredibly steep.

Comment: @Mikhail: Try reading so called "OpenGL Orange book" -> "OpenGL shading language 3rd edition". This should help you understand shaders better.

Comment: For example it is not clear how to bind two buffers to an OpenGL program at once.

Comment: @Mikhail: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Sampler#Binding_textures_to_samplers . Found it in less than a minute using google search.

Comment: I think we both understand that the learning curve is for OpenGL is quite steep and the concepts are esoteric.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have a program loaded and set up to read the texture (program1 in your code).  Assuming the vertex shader is already set up to pass the pixel shader texture coordinates to look up into the texture (in the below program this is "texcoord"), you should be able to change the pixel shader to something like this:

```
uniform texture2d texture;   // this is the greyscale texture
varying vec2 texcoord;       // passed from your vertex shader

void main() 
{  
    float luminance = tex2D(texture, texcoord).r;     // grab luminance texture
    gl_FragColor = convertToColor(luminance);         // run your function
}
```

this reads in the luminance texture and calls your function which converts a luminance to a color.  if your function only returns a 3-component rgb vector, you can change the last line to:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(convertToColor(luminance), 1.0);
```